# Security Testing for mobile applications

Tags: mobile, android-testing, security-testing

i'm new to the mobility domain. What should be the best approach to test the mobile applications security vulnerabilities. Please share the information and if anybody knows any tools to be use to achieve the same.

I'm looking for android and iOS platform.

Answer (score 0):

The only best way to test web applications or mobile applications is to follow OWASP guidelines. If you know little bit about the web app security, then surely you will aware of the OWASP. 
Similar to web applications, OWASP provide the top 10 risks for mobile also. Please refer OWASP site for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can run static code analysis on the app.
This will give a detailed report on the possible security issues with your app.
There are some tools available which will help you to do so.
Infact I have designed a web application which runs this analysis on .apk or .ipa file which a user uploads and displays the result of the scan in HTML format.
Feel free to explore https://thesecurityscan.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).